# How cast a subclass dynamically

Tags: java, class, casting

Scenario:
I have 2 different type of class: `Fus` and `Eth`. Both of them extend an abstract class called `Abs`.

Depending on some other info I have to cast `Abs` into `Fus` or `Eth`.

I have something like

```
while((rec == queue.poll()) != null) {
     insertInto(--rec-- Something here);
}
```

where `queue` is a `ArrayDeque<Abs>`, and `rec` is type of `Abs`.
What I'd like to achieve is to cast `rec` in method insertInto because I have implemented 2 method: one is `insertInto(Fus rec)` and the other `insertInto(Eth rec)`.

I want to cast `rec`.

Something like

```
Class typeOf;
if (cond1)
    typeOf = Eth.class;
else
    typeOf = Fus.class;
```

In this way, in the `insertInto(--rec--)` I could cast that rec with `typeOf`

**EDIT**. Going to try to explain me a little better.

What I want to achieve is: I already know, before the `while`, which kind of subclass I want to cast `rec` that means I want to cast directly `rec` in the right subclass. Something like:

`insertInto((typeOf) rec)`

so I can use overloading of method insertInto.
But of course this can't work, because typeOf is a `Class` object

**EDIT2**
Some other code hope it could explain what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Class typeOf;
if (condA) {
    typeOf = Fus.class;
} else {
    typeOf = Eth.class;
}

while ((rec = queue.poll()) != null) {
    insertInto((typeOf) rec); //Problem of course is here
}
```

Comment: `typeOf = myObject.getClass();` will return the actual class, but perhaps you would prefer `if (myObject instanceof Eth) { ... }`

Comment: What I want to avoid is to put an if inside the while

Comment: take a look at the ``instanceof`` keyword if you want a condition. Otherwise, your approach of overloading ``insertInto`` is the right way to go.

Comment: @f1sh yeah but the point is that I dont know how to cast inside the insertInto method

Comment: @AntonioCalì you mean inside the call to the insertInto method? Or inside the method itself?

Comment: @f1sh inside the call :)

Comment: Could someone explain me why I got a -1? Is too generic question? or not properly explained?

Comment: @AntonioCalì ``insertInto(rec instanceof Fus ? (Fus)rec:(Eth)rec);``, but that's very ugly.

Comment: @f1sh I totally want to avoid something like that, because I know already, before the while, in which kind of subclass i want to cast. Doing like that I ask for every Rec to check the instance of, but I know already before, and I totally want to cast directly

Comment: @AntonioCalì in that case i don't understand what you're asking.Why do you want to cast it anyways? You already stated that you have two overloads of ``insertInto`` with a Fus and an Eth parameter..

Comment: @f1sh Of course compiler complains me that can't find a `insertInto(Rec rec)` method. I've just implemented `insertInto(Eth rec)` and `insertInto(Fus rec)`

Comment: @AntonioCalì yes of course, because the compiler assumes that the queue contains ``Abs`` instances. Create a ``insertInto(Abs)`` method and leave it empty. It should never be called.

Comment: @f1sh I've tried, and as I expected, It calls the insertInto(Rec rec) method. I need to cast that rec in one of subclasses

Comment: @f1sh edited my question with some code, hope now it more understandable

Comment: Have you tried `knownType.cast(rec)`; where `knownType` is either `Fus.class` or `Eth.class`? Along with your overloaded `insertInto` case, you should be set.

Comment: I've tried, but of course because I have to implement a `insertInto(Abs rec)` for compiler, at runtime of course this method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using reflection.

```
Function<? extends Abs, ?> fn // Second one is your return type
if (cond1)
    fn = rec -> this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("insertInto", Eth.class).invoke(rec);

fn(rec)
```

Although i will not advice it

Comment: JRE7, Tell me if this could help. It looks like a Java8 from your reply

Comment: Function is just an object. You can do something like this . f = new Function<Eth,Object> {public Object apply(Eth eth){}}